# Override file in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

How to override the below file in magento 1 module ?

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php
```

Comment: You can add same file in local pool as app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php

Answer (score 0):

Copy
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`
To
`app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`